# Pseudo Code doesn't work for IDA Pro

Tags: decompiling, decompiler, ida

I'm currently having a problem with my IDA Pro which makes me unable to obtain Pseudo Code.

Whenever i try to press F5 or just go to Subviews -> Pseudo Code it won't do anything. It doesn't give any errors or anything, it's just doing nothing. I'm not sure if it's because i did something wrong in the settings.. It did work the 13th but now it doesn't.

Comment: Well, _something_ must have changed. There's no magic.